# latexdiff and \let

Tags: latexdiff

I added this line to my document to redefine `l@chapter` later:

```
\let\oldlchapter\l@chapter
```

Now latexdiff creates this, which doesn't compile:

```
\let\oldlchapter\DIFadd{\l@chapter
}
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: For people to be able to analyze the problem, you should provide two simple documents, one with the `\let`-statement and one without it, that result in this erroneous code. Apart from that, it is to be expected that `latexdiff` (and any other program with this functionality) fails at some point; marking differences in macro definitions in a way that does not break the code is probably beyond that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, latexdiff is designed to work with LaTeX document syntax, not raw TeX commands such as `\let`. In this case, a small change to latexdiff leads to the correct behaviour (see below - this has been implemented in the development version of [latexdiff on GitHub](https://github.com/ftilmann/latexdiff) and will be contained in versions 1.2.1 up (not yet released as of January 3, 2017).

More generally, use environment `\DIFnomarkup` (which you need to define to do nothing) to protect TeX commands from processing by latexdiff. see latexdiff manual or man pages for a more detailed explanation.

Required change to latexdiff:

Find the line:

```
  my $cmdoptseq='\\\\[\w\d\*]+'.$extraspace.'(?:(?:<'.$abrat0.'>|\['.$brat0.'\]|\{'. $pat_n . '\}|\(' . $coords .'\))'.$extraspace.')*';
```

and add one @ character such that it reads:

```
  my $cmdoptseq='\\\\[\w\d@\*]+'.$extraspace.'(?:(?:<'.$abrat0.'>|\['.$brat0.'\]|\{'. $pat_n . '\}|\(' . $coords .'\))'.$extraspace.')*';
```